EntityMetadataNotFoundError: No metadata for "User" was found
i have a nestjs project that i've published it with github actions and then i want to use the service of it in my other project for example (registerUser).
but i am getting this error:
EntityMetadataNotFoundError: No metadata for "User" was found.

also I have User in my data-source and it's imported from that project and it is correctly worked because the entity is added.
export const dataSourceOptions: DataSourceOptions = {
    type: 'mysql',
    host: configService.get('DB_HOST'),
    port: configService.get('DB_PORT'),
    username: configService.get('DB_USERNAME'),
    password: configService.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
    database: configService.get('DB_DATABASE'),
    // entities: ['dist/**/*.entity.js'],
    entities: [User],    
    synchronize: true,
}

is there any way to fix it?
Update:
this is my user.entity in user-management project:
@Entity()
export class User {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  firstName: string;

  @Column()
  lastName: string;

  @Column({ unique: true })
  username: string;

  @Column({ default: null })
  phoneNumber: string;

  email: string;

  @Column({ select: false })
  @Exclude()
  password: string;

  @Exclude()
  confirmPassword: string;
}

also i have User entity in my typeOrm configs in my user-management project and in my other project that uses User entity.
i think problem is that the register method is using User entity but the User that is in my other project is different.
I've included User in TypeOrmModule.forFeature in module and TypeOrmModule.forRoot in AppModule in both user-management and second project.
also the User entity in second project is imported from user-management.

Describe your user entity well. Can you show user.entity.ts file?

It's also possible that you should include the needed entity with TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User]) in module import.
https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database

@OSA413 I've include User in TypeOrmModule.forFeature in module and TypeOrmModule.forRoot in AppModule in both user-management and second project. ( also the User entity in second project is imported from user-management)
